# The determinant of a matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, determinant

In order get the determinant of$$\begin{pmatrix}
\lambda-n-1 & 1 & 2 & 2 & 1 & 1 & 1& 1 & \cdots &1 & 1 \\
1 & \lambda-2n+4 & 1 & 2 & 2 &2 &2&2 & \cdots &2&2 \\
2&1&\lambda-3n+9&1&2&3&3&3&\cdots & 3 &3\\
2&2&1&\lambda-3n+9&1&3&3&3&\cdots&3&3\\
1&2&2&1&\lambda-2n+4&2&2&2&\cdots&2&2\\
1&2&3&3&2&\lambda-2n+1&2&2&\cdots&2&2\\
1&2&3&3&2&2&\lambda-2n+1&2&\cdots&2&2\\
1&2&3&3&2&2&2&\lambda-2n+1&\cdots&2&2\\
\cdots&&\cdots&&\cdots&&\cdots&&\cdots&&\cdots\\
1&2&3&3&2&2&2&2&\cdots&\lambda-2n+1&2\\
1&2&3&3&2&2&2&2&\cdots&2&\lambda-2n+1 \end{pmatrix},$$ it seems that a lot of calculation is required. How to get it in a comparably faster way? Thanks.

Comment: Think about row reduction, perhaps. There is a pattern to the diagonal entries (as well as the rest of the matrix) can you exploit this? If you can row reduce the matrix to upper triangular form, the determinant will be the product of the diagonal entries.

Comment: I don't get the pattern of the entries. But maybe you could calculate the determinant for $1\times1$, $2\times2$, $3\times3$, and $4\times4$, guess a pattern to the answers, and then prove the pattern persists, using mathematical induction.